# Can I install anything (like Python), using a Linux LiveCD?

Tags: python, linux, unix, linux-mint, live-cd

I need Python on a Linux/Unix machine temporarily

Can I run, for example, a Linux Mint LiveCD and then install Python or emulate the install?

Or is a LiveCD strictly for **looking** at the distribution?

Comment: This site is for programming. You want something like ["Unix and Linux"](http://unix.stackexchange.com/?as=1)

Comment: Ah yes. Did'nt know about that site/section. But this is also about Python, so maybe someone here might know the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the program if you're using a LIVE CD-RW/USB. Surely you won't be able to install the program in a CD / DVD disk. Speaking in a traditional sense. The program could be "installed" for one-time use. It would be saved in memory. After you reboot, it would disappear. But when using a real live usb, for example, it would be "installed" in the media.

Comment: That's what I was hoping. That it would install in the memory. I will try it ;) Thank you

Comment: To clarify a bit, it's rare to run linux with entirely read-only filesystems.  Usually a variety of ramdisk is created, initialized from the CD or USB key, and the system runs off the ram copy.  Changes to the ramdisk would ordinarily be lost on shutdown, but many of the 'try it' modes offer a way to store runtime changes to an archive on a usb key, hard disk, etc so they can be recreated as the ramdisk is setup on the next boot.  Another option is a unionfs of a ramdisk which catches changes to a read only filesystem underneath it.

Answer (score 1):

Also, python comes with almost every distro. Just open a terminal and try `python -v`.

Comment: This would suite more as a comment rather than as a separate answer.

Comment: @JuozasDomarkas Completely disagree, it's an answer, and it's true.

Comment: I consider it an answer. The only distros I can think of that would not have python is a distro that is quite literally made up of `coreutils` (or `busybox`) and `bash`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what do you want to get? What's the question about live-cds?

> I need Python on a Linux/Unix machine temporarily

Most of all distros have Python just out-of-the-box

> Can I run, for example, a Linux Mint LiveCD and then install Python or emulate the install?

Of course, you can. But after reboot it will disappear. If you want it to remain after reboot, you should install the OS to the USB-drive, not to use it like live-CD.

> Or is a LiveCD strictly for looking at the distribution?

Yes, some kind of.